# Terraform AWS API Gateway integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I trying to replicate the build of an api gateway from an Udemy course in Terraform

On the course the tutor constructs a POST method integration on the console selecting "Lambda Function" as the "Integration Type" NOT selecting "Use Lambda Proxy Integration".

This works fine on the console but when I try to replicate this in Terraform the code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "build-table-post-integration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.testAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.build-table-resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.build-table-method-post.http_method
  type = "LAMBDA"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: expected type to be one of [HTTP AWS MOCK HTTP_PROXY AWS_PROXY], got LAMBDA
```

Fair enough but is the logical conclusion of this that a non-proxy integration of Lambda is not supported by Terraform?

Or am I missing the point?

If it's not supported my options are a proxy integration (not really keen) or use the Serverless Framework which does appear to support it (not hugely keen on that either)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non proxied Lambda integration requires you to use a type of `AWS`. This type also allows you to use DynamoDB, SNS, SQS and other AWS services.

The [AWS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html) also covers this:

> The type of integration with the specified backend. The valid value is
>
> - http or http_proxy: for integration with an HTTP backend
> - aws_proxy:    for integration with AWS Lambda functions;
> - aws: for integration with AWS Lambda functions or other AWS services, such as Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Simple Notification Service
>     or Amazon Simple Queue Service;
> - mock: for integration with API Gateway without invoking any backend.
>
> For more information about the integration types, see [integration:type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#type).